# LINQ - Select * from XML elements with a certain tag

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I've been looking at an example of LINQ from the following link; I've posted the code below the link.

Is it possible to modify this example so that the items returned in `var` contain all sub elements found in the items matching the doc.Descendants("person") filter?  I basically want this XML query to act like a SQL select * so I don't have to explicitly specify field names like they've done with drink, moneySpent, and zipCode.

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html#example_1

```
static void QueryTheData(XDocument doc)
{
     // Do a simple query and print the results to the console
     var data = from item in doc.Descendants("person")
                 select new
                 {
                      drink = item.Element("favoriteDrink").Value,
                      moneySpent = item.Element("moneySpent").Value,
                      zipCode = item.Element("personalInfo").Element("zip").Value
                  };
     foreach (var p in data)
         Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Would you have a container class that actually defines those property names? If not, consider that you can't use fields by name (without reflection) that your code doesn't see directly. You could probably make a tool that would mock up a container reflectively from your element names, but you wouldn't be able to use those fields directly.

Comment: It wasn't 100% what I wanted but it got me close enough to get a solution, and I thought it was good since I didn't really know what I was looking for in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP said he liked the answer posted, so I'll just resubmit it for science :)

```
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("person")
           select item;
```

The only problem with this is that data is an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, and you'll have to query the fields by string names.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't matter since it'll be a low scoring question anyways :p

Comment: I found this useful because I could switch .Descendants to .Elements() in which case I got the immediate child nodes only.  Cycling through that result with a for-each basically allowed me to get a name-value list for the subtags and values so I could form an sql query with them.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Do a simple query and print the results to the console 
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("person") 
             select item;
```

Comment: if he wants XElements, sure, it sounded to me like he wants named fields.